# OCR - turning tax forms into structured data with tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I can't seem to find any guidelines or tutorials on how to use OCR on things like tax forms to produce data in json format (or any other structured format). Do such tutorials exist? Or is there a fundamental reason this doesn't make sense? It seems like this would be of use to many people. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: OCR is a completely different concern than JSON data exchange. Making sense of the OCR'd data and then rendering it as JSON is (presumably) the responsibility of the program you're writing. Tesseract is not concerned with how its extracted data is ultimately consumed.

Comment: Oh completely agreed, I realize this is what I'm responsible for doing, I'm just not finding much in the way of material to get me started so thought I'd see if anyone had any good resources on top of mind. Also, it seems like a fairly well defined problem that I would imagine is a common pursuit so I'd expect there to be many people who have considered this before.